# Errors and failure building Android App Bundle in Unity with IL2CPP

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, android-ndk, il2cpp

I'm trying to build my Unity3D app as a .aab as Android Play Store requires this for new submissions now. Unfortunately i get errors and the build fails each time. I am using Unity editor version 2018.4.11f1 LTS and NDK version r16b. Any help is much appreciated!

[image: Unity configuration]

These are the two errors logged in the editor:

> Failed running C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2018.4.11f1\Editor\Data\il2cpp/build/il2cpp.exe --
>   convert-to-cpp --emit-null-checks --enable-array-bounds-check
>   --dotnetprofile="unityaot" --compile-cpp --libil2cpp-static --platform="Android" --architecture="ARMv7" --configuration="Release" --outputpath="D:\workflow\Temp\StagingArea\assets\bin\Data\Native\armeabi-v7a\libil2cpp.so"
>   --cachedirectory="D:\workflow\Assets..\Library\il2cpp_android_armeabi-v7a/il2cpp_cache"
>   --additional-include-directories="C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2018.4.11f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer/Tools\bdwgc/include"
>   --additional-include-directories="C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2018.4.11f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer/Tools\libil2cpp/include"
>   --tool-chain-path="C:/Users/seadn/AppData/Local/Android/Ndk/android-ndk-r16b"
>   --map-file-parser="C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2018.4.11f1\Editor\Data\Tools\MapFileParser\MapFileParser.exe"
>   --directory="D:\workflow\Temp\StagingArea\assets\bin\Data\Managed" --generatedcppdir="D:\workflow\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput"
>
> stdout: Building libil2cpp.so with AndroidToolChain   Output directory:
>   D:\workflow\Temp\StagingArea\assets\bin\Data\Native\armeabi-v7a   Cache
>   directory: D:\workflow\Library\il2cpp_android_armeabi-v7a\il2cpp_cache
>   ObjectFiles: 678 of which compiled: 0 Total compilation time: 1089
>   milliseconds. il2cpp.exe didn't catch exception:
>   Unity.IL2CPP.Building.BuilderFailedException:
>   C:\Users\seadn\AppData\Local\Android\Ndk\android-ndk-r16b\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++
>   @"C:\Users\seadn\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpD234.tmp" -o
>   "D:\workflow\Library\il2cpp_android_armeabi-v7a\il2cpp_cache\linkresult_A2AFE04C1AFC3C78C62C0D968E0224E6\libil2cpp.so"
>   -shared -Wl,-soname,libil2cpp.so -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--build-id --sysroot "C:\Users\seadn\AppData\Local\Android\Ndk\android-ndk-r16b\platforms\android-16\arch-arm"
>   -gcc-toolchain "C:\Users\seadn\AppData\Local\Android\Ndk\android-ndk-r16b\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64"
>   -target armv7-none-linux-androideabi -Wl,--wrap,sigaction -L "C:\Users\seadn\AppData\Local\Android\Ndk\android-ndk-r16b\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\4.9\libs\armeabi-v7a"
>   -lgnustl_static -llog -rdynamic -fuse-ld=gold.exe
>
> D:\workflow\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.cpp:40930:
>   error: undefined reference to 'Unity_WebRtcNetwork_Create'
>   D:\workflow\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.cpp:41186:
>   error: undefined reference to 'Unity_MediaNetwork_Create'
>   D:\workflow\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.cpp:41375:
>   error: undefined reference to 'Unity_DeviceApi_LastUpdate'
>   D:\workflow\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.cpp:41375:
>   error: undefined reference to 'Unity_DeviceApi_LastUpdate'
>   D:\workflow\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.cpp:41386:
>   error: undefined reference to 'Unity_DeviceApi_Devices_Length'
>   D:\workflow\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.cpp:41386:
>   error: undefined reference to 'Unity_DeviceApi_Devices_Length'
>   D:\workflow\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.cpp:41404:
>   error: undefined reference to 'Unity_DeviceApi_Devices_Get'
>   D:\workflow\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.cpp:41186:
>   error: undefined reference to 'Unity_MediaNetwork_Create'
>   D:\workflow\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.cpp:41205:
>   error: undefined reference to 'Unity_MediaNetwork_Configure'
>   D:\workflow\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.cpp:41291:
>   error: undefined reference to
>   'Unity_MediaNetwork_TryGetFrameDataLength'
>   D:\workflow\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.cpp:41280:
>   error: undefined reference to 'Unity_MediaNetwork_TryGetFrame'
>   D:\workflow\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.cpp:41291:
>   error: undefined reference to
>   'Unity_MediaNetwork_TryGetFrameDataLength'
>   D:\workflow\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.cpp:41280:
>   error: undefined reference to 'Unity_MediaNetwork_TryGetFrame'
>   D:\workflow\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.cpp:41219:
>   error: undefined reference to
>   'Unity_MediaNetwork_GetConfigurationState'
>   D:\workflow\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.cpp:41219:
>   error: undefined reference to
>   'Unity_MediaNetwork_GetConfigurationState'
>   D:\workflow\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.cpp:41022:
>   error: undefined reference to 'Unity_WebRtcNetwork_Update'
>   D:\workflow\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.cpp:41219:
>   error: undefined reference to
>   'Unity_MediaNetwork_GetConfigurationState'
>   D:\workflow\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.cpp:41249:
>   error: undefined reference to 'Unity_MediaNetwork_ResetConfiguration'
>   D:\workflow\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.cpp:41249:
>   error: undefined reference to 'Unity_MediaNetwork_ResetConfiguration'
>   D:\workflow\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.cpp:41302:
>   error: undefined reference to 'Unity_MediaNetwork_SetVolume'
>   D:\workflow\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.cpp:41302:
>   error: undefined reference to 'Unity_MediaNetwork_SetVolume'
>   D:\workflow\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.cpp:41312:
>   error: undefined reference to 'Unity_MediaNetwork_HasAudioTrack'
>   D:\workflow\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.cpp:41312:
>   error: undefined reference to 'Unity_MediaNetwork_HasAudioTrack'
>   D:\workflow\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.cpp:41323:
>   error: undefined reference to 'Unity_MediaNetwork_HasVideoTrack'
>   D:\workflow\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.cpp:41323:
>   error: undefined reference to 'Unity_MediaNetwork_HasVideoTrack'
>   D:\workflow\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.cpp:41344:
>   error: undefined reference to 'Unity_MediaNetwork_IsMute'
>   D:\workflow\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.cpp:41344:
>   error: undefined reference to 'Unity_MediaNetwork_IsMute'
>   D:\workflow\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.cpp:41334:
>   error: undefined reference to 'Unity_MediaNetwork_SetMute'
>   D:\workflow\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.cpp:41334:
>   error: undefined reference to 'Unity_MediaNetwork_SetMute'
>   D:\workflow\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.cpp:40930:
>   error: undefined reference to 'Unity_WebRtcNetwork_Create'
>   D:\workflow\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.cpp:40945:
>   error: undefined reference to 'Unity_WebRtcNetwork_Release'
>   D:\workflow\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.cpp:40945:
>   error: undefined reference to 'Unity_WebRtcNetwork_Release'
>   D:\workflow\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.cpp:40945:
>   error: undefined reference to 'Unity_WebRtcNetwork_Release'
>   D:\workflow\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.cpp:40978:
>   error: undefined reference to 'Unity_WebRtcNetwork_StartServer'
>   D:\workflow\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.cpp:40978:
>   error: undefined reference to 'Unity_WebRtcNetwork_StartServer'
>   D:\workflow\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.cpp:40992:
>   error: undefined reference to 'Unity_WebRtcNetwork_StopServer'
>   D:\workflow\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.cpp:40992:
>   error: undefined reference to 'Unity_WebRtcNetwork_StopServer'
>   D:\workflow\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.cpp:40959:
>   error: undefined reference to 'Unity_WebRtcNetwork_Connect'
>   D:\workflow\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.cpp:40959:
>   error: undefined reference to 'Unity_WebRtcNetwork_Connect'
>   D:\workflow\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.cpp:41071:
>   error: undefined reference to
>   'Unity_WebRtcNetwork_PeekEventDataLength'
>   D:\workflow\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.cpp:41110:
>   error: undefined reference to 'Unity_WebRtcNetwork_Dequeue'
>   D:\workflow\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.cpp:41071:
>   error: undefined reference to
>   'Unity_WebRtcNetwork_PeekEventDataLength'
>   D:\workflow\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.cpp:41110:
>   error: undefined reference to 'Unity_WebRtcNetwork_Dequeue'
>   D:\workflow\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.cpp:41049:
>   error: undefined reference to 'Unity_WebRtcNetwork_SendData'
>   D:\workflow\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.cpp:41049:
>   error: undefined reference to 'Unity_WebRtcNetwork_SendData'
>   D:\workflow\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.cpp:41060:
>   error: undefined reference to 'Unity_WebRtcNetwork_GetBufferedAmount'
>   D:\workflow\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.cpp:41060:
>   error: undefined reference to 'Unity_WebRtcNetwork_GetBufferedAmount'
>   D:\workflow\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.cpp:41012:
>   error: undefined reference to 'Unity_WebRtcNetwork_Shutdown'
>   D:\workflow\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.cpp:41012:
>   error: undefined reference to 'Unity_WebRtcNetwork_Shutdown'
>   D:\workflow\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.cpp:41022:
>   error: undefined reference to 'Unity_WebRtcNetwork_Update'
>   D:\workflow\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.cpp:41032:
>   error: undefined reference to 'Unity_WebRtcNetwork_Flush'
>   D:\workflow\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.cpp:41032:
>   error: undefined reference to 'Unity_WebRtcNetwork_Flush'
>   D:\workflow\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.cpp:41002:
>   error: undefined reference to 'Unity_WebRtcNetwork_Disconnect'
>   D:\workflow\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.cpp:41002:
>   error: undefined reference to 'Unity_WebRtcNetwork_Disconnect'
>   D:\workflow\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.cpp:40904:
>   error: undefined reference to 'Unity_WebRtcNetwork_IsAvailable'
>   D:\workflow\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.cpp:40915:
>   error: undefined reference to 'Unity_WebRtcNetwork_IsBrowserSupported'
>   D:\workflow\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.cpp:41149:
>   error: undefined reference to 'Unity_WebRtcNetwork_Peek'
>   D:\workflow\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.cpp:41160:
>   error: undefined reference to 'Unity_MediaNetwork_IsAvailable'
>   D:\workflow\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.cpp:41171:
>   error: undefined reference to 'Unity_MediaNetwork_HasUserMedia'
>   D:\workflow\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.cpp:41230:
>   error: undefined reference to
>   'Unity_MediaNetwork_GetConfigurationError'
>   D:\workflow\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.cpp:41355:
>   error: undefined reference to 'Unity_DeviceApi_Update'
>   D:\workflow\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.cpp:41365:
>   error: undefined reference to 'Unity_DeviceApi_RequestUpdate'
>   D:\workflow\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.cpp:41423:
>   error: undefined reference to 'Unity_SLog_SetLogLevel'
>   D:\workflow\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.cpp:41433:
>   error: undefined reference to 'Unity_InitAsync'
>   D:\workflow\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.cpp:41443:
>   error: undefined reference to 'Unity_PollInitState' clang++.exe:
>   error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
>   invocation)
>
> at
>   Unity.IL2CPP.Building.CppProgramBuilder.PostprocessObjectFiles(HashSet`1
>   objectFiles, CppToolChainContext toolChainContext)    at
>   Unity.IL2CPP.Building.CppProgramBuilder.Build(IBuildStatistics&
>   statistics)    at il2cpp.Program.DoRun(String[] args)    at
>   il2cpp.Program.Run(String[] args)    at il2cpp.Program.Main(String[]
>   args) stderr:
>
> Unhandled Exception: Unity.IL2CPP.Building.BuilderFailedException:
>   C:\Users\seadn\AppData\Local\Android\Ndk\android-ndk-r16b\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++
>   @"C:\Users\seadn\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpD234.tmp" -o
>   "D:\workflow\Library\il2cpp_android_armeabi-v7a\il2cpp_cache\linkresult_A2AFE04C1AFC3C78C62C0D968E0224E6\libil2cpp.so"
>   -shared -Wl,-soname,libil2cpp.so -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--build-id --sysroot "C:\Users\seadn\AppData\Local\Android\Ndk\android-ndk-r16b\platforms\android-16\arch-arm"
>   -gcc-toolchain "C:\Users\seadn\AppData\Local\Android\Ndk\android-ndk-r16b\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64"
>   -target armv7-none-linux-androideabi -Wl,--wrap,sigaction -L "C:\Users\seadn\AppData\Local\Android\Ndk\android-ndk-r16b\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\4.9\libs\armeabi-v7a"
>   -lgnustl_static -llog -rdynamic -fuse-ld=gold.exe
>
> D:\workflow\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.cpp:40930:
>   error: undefined reference to 'Unity_WebRtcNetwork_Create'
>   D:\workflow\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.cpp:41186:
>   error: undefined reference to 'Unity_MediaNetwork_Create'
>   D:\workflow\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.cpp:41375:
>   error: undefined reference to 'Unity_DeviceApi_LastUpdate'
>   D:\workflow\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.cpp:41375:
>   error: undefined reference to 'Unity_DeviceApi_LastUpdate'
>   D:\workflow\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.cpp:41386:
>   error: undefined reference to 'Unity_DeviceApi_Devices_Length'
>   D:\workflow\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.cpp:41386:
>   error: undefined reference to 'Unity_DeviceApi_Devices_Length'
>   D:\workflow\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.cpp:41404:
>   error: undefined reference to 'Unity_DeviceApi_Devices_Get'
>   D:\workflow\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.cpp:41186:
>   error: undefined reference to 'Unity_MediaNetwork_Create'
>   D:\workflow\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.cpp:41205:
>   error: undefined reference to 'Unity_MediaNetwork_Configure'
>   D:\workflow\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.cpp:41291:
>   error: undefined reference to
>   'Unity_MediaNetwork_TryGetFrameDataLength'
>   D:\workflow\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.cpp:41280:
>   error: undefined reference to 'Unity_MediaNetwork_TryGetFrame'
>   D:\workflow\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.cpp:41291:
>   error: undefined reference to
>   'Unity_MediaNetwork_TryGetFrameDataLength'
>   D:\workflow\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.cpp:41280:
>   error: undefined reference to 'Unity_MediaNetwork_TryGetFrame'
>   D:\workflow\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.cpp:41219:
>   error: undefined reference to
>   'Unity_MediaNetwork_GetConfigurationState'
>   D:\workflow\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.cpp:41219:
>   error: undefined reference to
>   'Unity_MediaNetwork_GetConfigurationState'
>   D:\workflow\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.cpp:41022:
>   error: undefined reference to 'Unity_WebRtcNetwork_Update'
>   D:\workflow\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.cpp:41219:
>   error: undefined reference to
>   'Unity_MediaNetwork_GetConfigurationState'
>   D:\workflow\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.cpp:41249:
>   error: undefined reference to 'Unity_MediaNetwork_ResetConfiguration'
>   D:\workflow\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.cpp:41249:
>   error: undefined reference to 'Unity_MediaNetwork_ResetConfiguration'
>   D:\workflow\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.cpp:41302:
>   error: undefined reference to 'Unity_MediaNetwork_SetVolume'
>   D:\workflow\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.cpp:41302:
>   error: undefined reference to 'Unity_M

and:

> Exception: C:\Program
>   Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2018.4.11f1\Editor\Data\il2cpp/build/il2cpp.exe
>   did not run properly! UnityEditorInternal.Runner.RunProgram
>   (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, System.String exe, System.String args,
>   System.String workingDirectory,
>   UnityEditor.Scripting.Compilers.CompilerOutputParserBase parser) (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/BuildUtils.cs:130)
>   UnityEditorInternal.Runner.RunManagedProgram (System.String exe,
>   System.String args, System.String workingDirectory,
>   UnityEditor.Scripting.Compilers.CompilerOutputParserBase parser,
>   System.Action`1[T] setupStartInfo) (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/BuildUtils.cs:73)
>   UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder.RunIl2CppWithArguments
>   (System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] arguments, System.Action`1[T]
>   setupStartInfo, System.String workingDirectory) (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:370)
>   UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder.ConvertPlayerDlltoCpp (System.String
>   inputDirectory, System.String outputDirectory, System.String
>   workingDirectory, System.Boolean platformSupportsManagedDebugging) (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:351)
>   UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder.Run () (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:211)
>   UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPUtils.RunIl2Cpp (System.String tempFolder,
>   System.String stagingAreaData,
>   UnityEditorInternal.IIl2CppPlatformProvider platformProvider,
>   System.Action`1[T] modifyOutputBeforeCompile,
>   UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry runtimeClassRegistry) (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:35)
>   UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.RunIl2Cpp.Execute
>   (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at
>   :0)
>   UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks
>   (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at
>   :0)
>   UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcess
>   (UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String stagingAreaData,
>   System.String stagingArea, System.String playerPackage, System.String
>   installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName,
>   UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry
>   usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at
>   :0)
>   UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess
>   (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args,
>   UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) (at
>   :0)
>   UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess
>   (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget
>   target, System.String installPath, System.String companyName,
>   System.String productName, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height,
>   UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry
>   usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/PostprocessBuildPlayer.cs:286)
>   UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

Answer (score 0):

The undefined references were referring to a WebRTC plugin in the Unity project which did not support IL2CPP. I updated the plugin to a newer version which supports IL2CPP and successfully built the .aab file.

Comment: Strangely, although I have a successful .aab file, when i uploaded it to Play console it says that it does not contain any 64bit code despite the fact that I checked the ARM64 target architecture!